# How to load system fonts in Libgdx ? Mainly for android. And how can i get the list of available fonts?

Tags: android, fonts, system, libgdx

I have been working with libgdx for some time. And I know that to load fonts from .ttf files added to the assets folder I can use "FreeTypeFontGenerator".

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(gdx.files.internal("data/samplefont.ttf"));
font = generator.generateFont(12);
generator.dispose();
```

But I could not find anywhere how to use the fonts available in android. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use System installed fonts in android. You need to place ttf file in assets directory to use above library in android.